# How do I get total hours from start- end activity ? - Django model

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-3.1

I have the following entries from the model with two variable days.

```
class Log_hour(models.Model):
activity_no = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
activityDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, null=True)
start_activity = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
end_activity = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, null=True)
total_hours = ?


def __str__(self):
    return self.activity_no
```

How do I get the total hours? my goal is to sent total hours to an sms using twilio api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a property to the model like (which will work for datetime fields as well):

```
    @property
    def total_hours(self):
        "Returns the delta between start_activity and end_activity in hours"
        delta = self.end_activity - self.start_activity 
        hours = delta.total_seconds() / 3600
        return hours
```